# Fragment Volley

Tags: fragment, kotlin, gson, volley

Por que este codigo me funciona correctamente si es un activity y si es un fragment, ni me da errores ni me muestra nada, se queda simplemente con el progressbar?

```
class FragJornadaActual1 : Fragment() {

    val TAG = "json_request"
    val URL = "https://miurl"    

    override fun onCreate(savedInstanceState: Bundle?) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState)
        setRetainInstance(true)
    }

    override fun onCreateView(inflater: LayoutInflater?, container: ViewGroup?, savedInstanceState: Bundle?): View? {

        val view = inflater!!.inflate(R.layout.fragment_bottom, container, false)

        val interminateBar: ProgressBar= view.findViewById<ProgressBar>(R.id.interminateBar)

        val jsonObjReq = JsonObjectRequest(Request.Method.GET, URL, null, com.android.volley.Response.Listener<JSONObject> { response ->
            setUpAdapter(response)
            interminateBar.visibility = View.GONE
        },
                com.android.volley.Response.ErrorListener {
                    interminateBar.visibility = View.GONE
                })

        MyApplication.instance?.addToRequestQueue(jsonObjReq, TAG)

        return view
    }




    private fun setUpAdapter(response: JSONObject) {

        val gson = Gson()

        val model = gson.fromJson<JornadasList1>(response.toString(), JornadasList1::class.java)
        val jor = model.jonadas

        recyclerView.layoutManager = GridLayoutManager(getActivity(), 1)

         val adapter = JornadasAdapter1(activity, jor !!)
        recyclerView.adapter = adapter
    }
}
```

Y el adaptador

```
class JornadasAdapter1(internal var context: Context, internal var jornadasList1: List<Jornadas1>) : RecyclerView.Adapter<JornadasAdapter1.ViewHolder>() {

    override fun onCreateViewHolder(parent: ViewGroup, viewType: Int): ViewHolder {
        val itemView = LayoutInflater.from(parent.context)
                .inflate(R.layout.jornadas_row, parent, false)
        return ViewHolder(itemView)
    }

    @SuppressLint("SetTextI18n")
    override fun onBindViewHolder(holder: ViewHolder, position: Int ) {
        val jornadas = jornadasList1[position]

        holder!!.itemView.setOnClickListener {

            Toast.makeText(context, "El partido esta  " + jornadas.estadoPartido,
                    Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show()            
        }

        holder.textFecha.text = jornadas.fecha
        holder.textHora.text = jornadas.hora
        holder.textEstado.text = "  -  " + jornadas.estadoPartido + "  -  "
        holder.textEquipoLocal.text = jornadas.nomLocal
        holder.textResulLocal.text = jornadas.resulLocal
        holder.textEquipovisi.text = jornadas.nomVisitante
        holder.textResulVisi.text = jornadas.resulVisitante
        holder.textArbitro.text = "Arbitro: "+jornadas.arbitro

        if(holder.textArbitro.text != "Arbitro: "){
            holder.textArbitro.text = "Arbitro: "+jornadas.arbitro
        }else{
            holder.textArbitro.text = ""
        }

        Picasso.with(context)
                .load(jornadas.escudoLocal)
                .resize(80, 80)
                .noFade()
                //.fit()
                .into(holder.imageEscLocal)

        Picasso.with(context)
                .load(jornadas.escudoVisitante)
                .resize(80, 80)
                .noFade()
                //.fit()
                .into(holder.imageEscVisil)
    }

    override fun getItemCount(): Int = jornadasList1.size

    class ViewHolder(view: View) : RecyclerView.ViewHolder(view) {

        var textFecha: TextView = view.findViewById(R.id.tv_Fecha)as TextView
        var textHora: TextView = view.findViewById(R.id.tv_Hora) as TextView
        var textEstado: TextView = view.findViewById(R.id.tv_Estado) as TextView
        var textEquipoLocal: TextView = view.findViewById(R.id.tv_Equipo_Local) as TextView
        var textResulLocal: TextView = view.findViewById(R.id.tv_Result_Local)as TextView
        var imageEscLocal: ImageView = view.findViewById(R.id.tv_esc_local) as ImageView
        var textEquipovisi: TextView = view.findViewById(R.id.tv_Equipo_Visitante) as TextView
        var textResulVisi: TextView = view.findViewById(R.id.tv_Result_Visitante) as TextView
        var imageEscVisil: ImageView = view.findViewById(R.id.tv_esc_visi) as ImageView
        var textArbitro: TextView = view.findViewById(R.id.tv_Arbitro) as TextView
    }
}
```

si necesitan algo mas lo dicen pero ya digo que como activity si funciona.

Comment: No veo la variable `interminateBar` declarada en el fragment.

Comment: @EinerSantanaR Asi?, pues tampoco funciona

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`onCreate` se ejecuta primero que `onCreateView` por lo que la propiedad `view` no contiene ninguna referencia ya que onCreateView es quien proporcia dicha referencia y asi poder obtener la referencia del `ProgressBar`:

Intenta hacer tu petición en el método `onCreateView`, en vez de en el metodo `onCreate`, cuando ya hayas inflado la vista:

```
override fun onCreateView(inflater: LayoutInflater?, container: ViewGroup?, savedInstanceState: Bundle?): View? {

        val view = inflater!!.inflate(R.layout.fragment_bottom, container, false)

        RequestQueue queue = Volley.newRequestQueue(getActivity());

        val interminateBar: ProgressBar= view.findViewById<ProgressBar>(R.id.interminateBar)            

        val jsonObjReq = JsonObjectRequest(Request.Method.GET, URL, null, com.android.volley.Response.Listener<JSONObject> { response ->
                setUpAdapter(response)
                interminateBar.visibility = View.GONE
            },
            com.android.volley.Response.ErrorListener {
                interminateBar.visibility = View.GONE
            })

        queue.add(jsonObjReq);

        return view
 }
```

Comment: Post 1 editado tampoco muesta nada, solo el progressBar

Comment: Confirma varios puntos. No tienes el progressbar como gone en la vista? Agrega un Log.d("error", "ERROR" en el callback de error para comprobar que el request no este lanzando ningun error.

Comment: no se hacer log.d

Comment: Acabo de actualizar mi respuesta con el Log.e en el metodo ErrorListener . Solo tendras que importar la clase. Ejecuta tu aplicacion y mira el logcat. Si el request da algun error, el logcat te lo mostrara.

Comment: *Log.e("error", error.getMessage()) - getMessage *en rojo

Comment: Cual es el mensaje de error que muestra?

Comment: [Continuemos el debate en el chat](http://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/71817/discussion-between-rafel-c-f-and-einer).

Comment: No muestra mensage